# Issue with getting data to Splunk App for Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: splunk

I am very new to splunk, We are trying to monitor our hyperledger fabric network with the Splunk App for fabric in the Splunk enterprise. We have a hyperledger fabric network with version 2.2.2.

I installed the app and followed the instructions specified in https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4605/#/details.

I also setup the fabric-logger and I could see the fabric-logger is running and it is able to fetch the blocks and event details from the peer from which it is connected to.

In the Splunk, I see this error: `Search peer indexer-0 has the following message: Received event for unconfigured/disabled/deleted index=hyperledger_logs with source="source::fabriclogger" host="host::fabric-logger-6b79d77b99-bncwj" sourcetype="sourcetype::fabric_logger:endorser_transaction". So far received events from 1 missing index(es).`

I have the HEC enabled and I also have the index `hyperledger_logs`.

I don´t see any errors in the logs of fabric-logger or in the indexer.

But I am not seeing any data in Splunk.

Please find the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear - the index "hyperledger_logs" does not exist or is disabled.  You say you have it, but is it possible it exists on the search head and not on the indexers?  Defining an index on one does not define it on the other.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am very new to splunk. Could you please let me know, how I can check the index in the inderers? I can see the indexes from the UI, the indexes are present and it is enabled. I have added the screenshot in the question above.

Comment: If the indexers have the UI enabled then it's a simple matter of signing in checking the index list the same you did on the search head (SH).
If the indexers do not have the UI enabled then you may be able to check by running a search from the SH: `| rest /services/data/indexes | search title="hyperledger_logs"`.  You should see one entry for each indexer plus the search head.

Comment: Also, make sure the HEC input allows access to the hyperledger_logs index.